# jQuery плагин просмотр фото (с масштабированием под размер экрана)

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста плагин  jQuery для просмотра фотографий с **масштабированием под размер пользовательского монитора**.

Например вот здесь http://cvetybukety.ru/uslugi_102.html
просто выводится полноразмерное изображение и на маленьком экране выглядит ужасно :(

Comment: так у вас там на сайте фотки изначально не были оптимизированы под большие экраны (большинство фоток 800/1200 или 1200/800), красиво их ничто не растянет. Лучше сделайте их поменьше - 800*600 тоже все можно рассмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт найден!
http://www.ionden.com/widgets/wg/zoom/index2.php

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').not('#fullview').click(function(){
$('body').append('<img id="fullview" src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" style="width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute;"/>');
});
});
</script>
```

**trollface**

Comment: Так тоже пойдет, хотя хочется красоты, переключения по стрелочкам и тд) Все-равно спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите демо [jmFullZoom](http://www.moretech.it/demo/plugins/jmFullWall/demo01.html)